# DDD: How to refactor (wrap) remote service call into domain?

Tags: domain-driven-design

There is a service class `FooService` and method named `fetchFoos` that calls remote service, deserialize the JSON response and returns graph of value objects (starting with root `Foo` object). For now, there is no other behavior with this remote service, i.e. we are just fetching some 3rd party data. Speaking in DDD terms, this is closed bounded context with sole purpose of providing data, using its own models.

We may leave this method as a service; but... it seems it would be better if we may rename it to something more 'linguistic'.

For example, we could migrate singleton service to a simple bean named: `FooFetcher` (any better name?) and have method `fetchFooForBar()` that does the same. Then instead of injecting the service, we would simple create a new instance of this object and use it.

I even think that `FooFetcher` is a wrong domain name, it should be just `Foos` and the method would be `fetchForBar()`.

However, some other ppl think that should come from a repository - so basically, we would just need to rename the `FooService` to `FooRepository`.

Any collective wisdom on how to encapsulate remote services in DDD?

Comment: Would this be any different from a repository that is talking to a MySQL or other relational database over the wire? In addition to naming, what about the couple? What is the impact if the remote system is down? How likely is it to go down?

Comment: Its very unlikely to remote to be down. Still, its not in our control, like MySql, which we _assume_ it is up all the time.

Comment: How is this "graph of value objects" used ?

Comment: It is just converted to model objects (for example, entities) and value objects relevant to the application.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Foo is an entity in your bounded context, you can think of this service as an infrastructure service that will be invoked from a repository.

In the following example, I named the fetcher "FooFetchService" and it has a method called "getFoo" return a JSON string with the "contents" of the foo object

```
public interface FooRepository {
     public Foo getById(String fooId);
}

public class RemoteFooRepository implements FooRepository {

    @Inject
    FooFetchService fooFetchService;

    public Foo getById(String fooId) {

         String returnedFoo = fooFetchService.getFoo(fooId);

         /* add code here to deserialize the JSON contents of the returnFoo variable to an object Foo  foo*/
         return foo;
    }

}
```

RemoteFooRepository is just an implementation of FooRepository which happens to retrieve a Foo via some remote service. You can inject this in any of your other services classes that need it.